# Error in batch variable expansion with replacement containing parentheses

Tags: batch-file

I have the following Batch script which replaces occurrences of `{path}` in a text file with a path:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set myPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\foo

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (template.txt) do (
    set line=%%A
    set line=!line:{path}=%myPath%!
    echo !line!
)
```

When I run this script I get the error message

```
\foo! was unexpected at this time.
```

If I remove the parentheses in the path it works as expected. How can I solve this problem? I cannot have quotes around the path in the text file so putting quotes around the path in the set statement is not an option.

Comment: `%path%` is already a system variable. Please change your variable name to something else.

Comment: Also, if you put quotes to the left of the variable name and to the right of the value (like `set "file_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\foo"`) then you get the benefit of quotes without the quotes actually appearing in the output.

Comment: @SomethingDark Indeed, I temporarily forgot that; maybee because I spelled it in lowercase. I have now changed the name to *myPath*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set path=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\foo` first (this folder may be elsewhere, this variable is here to find it anyway), and surround the replacement `set` with quotes (see below).

Corrected program:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set pathval=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\foo

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (template.txt) do (
    set line=%%A
    REM Please note the quotes around the affectation. It avoids an interpretation.
    set "line=!line:{path}=%pathval%!"
    echo !line!
)
```

Side note: even with `setlocal`, avoid to name a variable `path`...

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "mypath=C:\Program Files (x86)\foo"

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (q71593680.txt) do (
    set "line=%%A"
    CALL :changeline
    echo !line!
)

FOR %%c IN ("%mypath%") DO for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (q71593680.txt) do (
    set "line=%%A"
    set "line=!line:{path}=%%~c!"
    echo !line!
)

GOTO :EOF

:changeline
set "line=!line:{path}=%mypath%!"
GOTO :eof
```

The problem is that the `)` in the substitution-string is being taken as the closing parenthesis of the `do`.

Solution : make an internal subroutine as shown.

Use `set "var1=data"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces.

Don't use `path` as a variablename - it's a reserved word in batch, meaning the sequence in which the directories are searched to find an executable that isn't in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, I don't see why defining a subroutine is necessary.

Comment: I've added another method. The object is to avoid having the `)` parsed when the substitution is made for `mypath`. If you were substituting a literal, then you would need to escape the `)` with a caret `^)`.

Comment: If I add double quotes around the whole assignment (like you showed) the code works so that should be sufficient.